# Is this integral finite?

Tags: calculus

could someone tell me if this integral is finite when the parameter s is in $]0;1[$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \frac{|e^{i(y\mid\xi)} - 1|^2}{|y|^{2s+d}} dy $$

since $2s+d > d$ there is no problem to say it is finite outside the ball $B(0;1)$ but I don't see why it would be inside (since it is said implicitely in a book that this integral is finite I am a little bothered )

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singularity in $0$ is integrable if the integrand can be dominated by $\lvert y\rvert^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > -d$.

Here, the numerator of the integrand provides a factor that can be dominated by $\lvert y\rvert^2$, since

$$\lvert e^{it}-1\rvert^2 = (1-\cos t)^2 + \sin^2 t = 2 (1-\cos t) = 4 \sin^2 \frac{t}{2} \leqslant t^2.$$

So overall, near $0$, the integrand is dominated by $\lvert y\rvert^{2-2s-d}$, and $2(1-s) > 0$, so the singularity in $0$ is integrable. Since, as you observed, outside the unit ball, the integrand is dominated by $\lvert y\rvert^{-2s-d}$, the integral is finite indeed.

Comment: It is all clear now, thank you very much for this answer